# Find out if profileSettings.profileVisible in GPGS android API?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have an android app and I'm using the java apis for accessing Google Play Games Services. After the user logged in, I can submit the leaderboard entry and later fetch it to show in the global leaderboard for my game.

However, there is an option in the user profile that players can disable showing up in the global leaderboard. I'd like to be able to show a message to the player explaining why he's not there if it was the case that he disabled the option (though he disabled it himself, and should have known what he was doing, it's better safe than sorry).

In the web apis I can see the field in the Player "class" ([here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players#methods)):

```
"profileSettings": {
    "kind": "games#profileSettings",
    "profileVisible": boolean
},
```

However, in the Java/android APIs, I can't for the life of me find this option. Nor the Player class nor the leaderboard classes show this option. The result is that for those players the submit works as expected but the player is not listed in the leaderboard later.

Is there a way to get this option without resorting to apis call by hand (that I wouldn't even know how to do)?